# Create a video file with a specific duration using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I want to record a video file from an IP camera with a duration of 30 minutes (2 fps).

My problem is that the video file duration is not exactly 30 minutes, it's about 28-29 minutes.
It's because of the fact that the camera FPS is not exactly 2, it's changed. So if I set the fps in the VideoWriter to 2 the duration of the video file is less than 30 minutes.

Can I change the video file duration (or changing the FPS) using the VideoWriter?

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("/home/ws/Desktop/temp/asd.jpg");
std::string fileName("/home/ws/Desktop/temp/asd.avi");
int fourcc = 0;
cv::VideoWriter Video(fileName,
fourcc,
1,
frame.size(),
true);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
Video.write(frame);
}
std::cout << "fps: " << Video.get(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) << "\n";
Video.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 5000);
std::cout << "fps: " << Video.get(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) << "\n";
Video.release();

}
```

Edit:
Can I just change the header of the video file to change the FPS to make it length of 30 minutes?

Comment: Typical way is to drop frames are add duplicate frames if the actual fps doesnt match the desired fps.

Comment: not sure, I didnt ever try to just change the header. But keep in mind that this might distort your video, for example if the reason for your wrong number of frames is a gap in the recording, (e.g. for 2 minutes in a row, no frames were recorded), "stretching" the whole video will give you wrong points in time where the frames are displayed. Adding duplicates or dropping frames during recording could handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate total number of frame of video to solve your problem. In your case, the total number of frame is 2 * 60 * 30 = 3600. I hope Python code below could help you:

```
import cv2


video_path = <video_path>
video_reader = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 2, (<frame_width>,<frame_height>))

while True:
    if not ret or video_reader.get(1) > 3600:
        break
    video_writer.write(frame)

video_writer.release()
video_reader.release()
```

Comment: That not help. because if I do it, the video duration is 30 minute, but in realty it more then 30 minutes.

Comment: Can I just change the header of the video file to change the FPS to make it length of 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answere I learned from avobe just change some codes.

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(<video path>)

fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mpeg')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
         out.write(frame)
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
      out.release() #This is important
      cap.release() #This is important
      break
```